# Mule4 Dataweave transformation

Tags: mule, transformation, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I need to transform the below JSON

Input :-

```
{
    "type": "donut",
    "weight-unit": "lb",
    "price-unit": "$/lb",
    "price": 10.75,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "10011", "type": "Original","weight": 500},
                    { "id": "10021", "type": "Chocolate","weight": 200, "price": 11.75 },
                    { "id": "10031", "type": "Blueberry", "weight": 250, "price": 11.75  },
                    { "id": "10041", "type": "Devil's Food", "weight": 150}
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "50011", "type": "None", "price": 0 },
            { "id": "50021", "type": "Glazed", "price": 45.23},
            { "id": "50051", "type": "Sugar", "price": 34.1},
            { "id": "50071", "type": "Powdered Sugar", "price": 21.11},
            { "id": "50061", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles", "price": 34.43 },
            { "id": "50031", "type": "Chocolate", "price": 87.40},
            { "id": "50041", "type": "Maple", "price": 64.11}
        ]
}
```

The output that I want is

Output :-

```
{
    "type": "donut",
    "ChocolateFlavoredGlazedDonut" : {
        "weight": 200,
        "unit": "kg",
        "price": 56.98,
        "unit": "$/kg",
    },
    "ChocolateFlavoredSprinklesDonut" : {
        "weight": 200,
        "unit": "kg",
        "price": 46.18,
        "unit": "$/kg",
    },
    "BlueberryFlavoredSugarDonut" : {
        "weight": 250,
        "unit": "kg",
        "price": 45.85,
        "unit": "$/kg",
    },
    "OriginalGlazedDonut" : {
        "weight": 500,
        "unit": "kg",
        "price": 45.23,
        "unit": "$/kg",
    },
        "OriginalMapleDonut" : {
        "weight": 500,
        "unit": "kg",
        "price": 64.11,
        "unit": "$/kg",
    },
        "OriginalSugarDonut" : {
        "weight": 500,
        "unit": "kg",
        "price": 34.1,
        "unit": "$/kg",
    },
}
```

Explanantion:-

"BatterName + ToppingName" : {
"weight": 500(batter weight),
"unit": "kg"(hard coded),
"price": 34.1(batter price + topping price),
"unit": "$/kg"(hard coded,
}

For example if Batter Name is "Chocolate", then there will be 6 toppings for Chocolate batter and so on for each batter. So total batter number is 4 and topping is 8 , I want 32 items in the final output

Comment: Hi. welcome to Stack Overflow. The JSONs you shared are quite large and will take the readers a lot of effort to understand the logic. Please add what is the logic behind the transformation and if there is anything that you have tried.

Comment: Hi @aparajitatiwary. The output doesn't has an obvious relationship with the input. It will not be possible to provide an answer until you clarify the logic on how to transform the input to output. Then is a matter of implementing that logic in DataWeave. If you still have issues after adding the explanation then it would be appropriate to answer. Kindly read Stackoverflow guidelines on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Added explaination

Comment: The expected output doesn't has 32 elements like the updated explanation says. And from where the word "Flavored" is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a cross join on toppings and batters. You can use [`join`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-join) from `dw::core::Arrays` to do that. It accepts the 2 arrays as input along with two joining criteria (which are inline functions). For that you can just pass a function that always returns `true` (or any other static value but it should be same in both criteria functions) so the function will merge every item with every item, and you will get all combos possible.

I noticed that the names of the snack after combining is not very straight forward, so I crated a separated function for that.

```js
%dw 2.0
import join from dw::core::Arrays
import capitalize from dw::core::Strings
output application/json

fun getComboName(batterName, toppingName, snackType) = 
    capitalize(batterName) 
    ++ (if(lower(batterName) != "original")("Flavoured") else "")
    ++ (if(lower(toppingName) != "none") capitalize((toppingName splitBy " ")[-1]) else "")
    ++ capitalize(snackType) 
---
join(
    payload.batters.batter,
    payload.topping,
    (a) -> true,
    (a) -> true
)
reduce ((combo, acc={"type": payload."type"}) -> {
    (acc),
    (getComboName(combo.l."type", combo.r."type", payload."type")): {
        weight: combo.l.weight,
        unit: "kg",
        price: (combo.l.price default 0) + (combo.r.price default 0),
        unit: "\$/kg"
    }
})
```